# How to move Outlook from one computer to another?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, transfer

I know I can move the `outlook.pst` file, but what about the email accounts and other configuration?

I'd hate having to insert the email accounts one by one again, so are the configuration settings for email accounts stored and how can I migrate them?

Comment: You can use one of the Backup programs (trial mode should do just fine) to backup these settings on one PC and then restore on another (passwords are encrypted using specific UserID, so they will not be restored on another PC (Outlook will ask for a password again), unless program knows how to decrypt them). I did it using KLS Backup. I'm sure there are other programs that can do the same.

Comment: Is there a file to copy?  Or do you have to backup the whole system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I last wrote this for Outlook 2003 but hopefully a lot of it will still apply.

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP030822101033.aspx

Most critical files are all in one place:

```
    c:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

    outcmd.dat     : toolbar settings
    outlook.nk2    : nickname cache
    outlook.srs    : send-and-receive settings (if customized)
    outlook.xml    : navigation pane settings
    outlprnt       : print styles

    vbaproject.otm : all outlook macros
```